# remove weird space

Tags: html, css

**Question:**

how do i get rid of the space shown in first image?

**more info and code:**

i have a list of contacts that i want arranged on above the other. when the user mouses over the contact's name, a contact card pops up. on the contact card, i want to have an e-mail icon.

when the email icon is in the right top corner - there are no problems. however, when i add padding to move it to the bottom right corner of the contact card, a weird space appears between the contact names when the page first loads. however, after i mouse over and the contact card appears, the weird space disappears and the contact list appears the way i want it to appear

here is my code:
**html:**

```
<div id="ball">
      <div id="thisisatest" onmouseover="showIt('/images/em.png', 'tomJustice')" onmouseout="hideIt('tomJustice')" >       
            <img src="/images/bluesquare.png" height="15" width="15" ></img>     tom Justice
            <img src="" id="tomJustice" style="margin-left: auto; overflow:hidden; padding-top: 20%" onclick="showIt('/images/card22.png', 'tomJustice2')" onmouseout="hideIt('tomJustice2')">
            <img src="" id="tomJustice2" style="display:none"></img>
            </br>
      </div>
... other contacts
</div>
```

Comment: what is in the JavaScript function `showIt(imgPath, ID_name)` ?

Comment: You have to set the height of the image, or the browser can't calculate the vertical position of the element.

Comment: can you show an working demo it will be better to see the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you not just giving an

```
position:absolute;
```

and an

```
right: 0; bottom: 0;
```

you can just position inside a div

Comment: fix the syntax & spelling for you

Comment: genius! position had to be relative though, not absolute, and the right, bottom positions needed some adjustment, but it works. thanks!

Comment: no problem glad i could help, and yes my mistake the position its getting late